# The correct content-type is set, but i the .ipa File is treated like a .zip File

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, download, mime-types, ipa

i have written a small Rails Application where i can upload three Files which i needed to distribute the adhoc builds over-the-air. This includes a *.ipa* File, a *.mobileprovisioning* File and a *.plist* File.

The Problem is now, when i click on the link to the *.ipa* File the File is treated as a normal Download and my iDevices asks me where to store the file.

```
curl -I example.com/path/to/App.ipa
```

generates this output

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2012 13:55:08 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Thu, 25 Oct 2012 10:23:07 GMT
ETag: "742-1351160587000"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 742
Connection: keep-alive
```

i think **application/octet-stream** is the correct content type. What am i doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Regards,
buk

Comment: @borrrden yes. Check the docs I just linked.

Comment: Fascinating, will this work with Enterprise apps as well?

Comment: @borrrden can i accept the answers by clicking the hook?

Comment: Yes, click the check mark near an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An .ipa file is just a (not very well disguised) zip file (it's just renamed to `.ipa`). Maybe when you set the generic `application/octet-stream` MIME-type, the Safari browser on iOS looks at the actual contents of the file, finds out that it's actually a ZIP archive and proceeds. By the way, it seems to me that you want to do some in-house or ad-hoc distribution of iOS apps. In this case, you should really direct the user towards the manifest.plist file which (an URL beginning with `itms-services://`) in order iOS to know that it needs to look for an application bundle and then download and install it.

[Documentation here.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1829415&seqNum=16)

Comment: Hi H2CO3


yes i want to distribute ios-ad-hoc-builds to our customers to test them before they went to the App Store. 

You can generate adhoc-builds in Xcode and get a generated *.ipa* File and a *.plist* File. These two files you can upload to a folder on your webserver, add a html file with the itms-services:// link you posted before and the adhoc-build is going to be installed on your device.

When i click on the link to the plist File, the content of the plist file is shown in iOS Safari and no adhoc-build installation is happening.

Comment: @buk I know all this. Then what's the question?

Comment: the question is, how to set the `application/octet-stream ipa` and `text/xml plist`content type to start the installation after clicking the links.

Comment: @buk server configuration maybe? The instructions I linked say that the 'web page should be set' in a manner that the extensions and MIME-types arre associated correctly. What kind of webserver (software) are you using?

Comment: this is a standard Rails Application so the Webserver i am using is Webrick

Comment: @buk Thanks for the accept! I've found [this class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPResponse.html) with which you can set the content type. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps below:

1. Upload .ipa file to your server
2. Create a file <app_name>.plist with content as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>items</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software-package</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>https://www.anysite.com/application/your_app.ipa</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>com.example.helloworld</string>
            <key>bundle-version</key>
            <string>1.0.0</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>App Name</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Replace "**bundle-identifier**" and "**title**" with your value.

3. Upload .plist file to your server
4. Create a link in a HTML file as below:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://www.anysite.com/application/your_app.plist">
Download
</a>
```

5. Use your iphone, open a browser and go to that page, click "Download" link. Your IPhone will install the app.