# File downloads on iOS save as .txt

Tags: apache, .htaccess, download, safari

When I try download a file on Safari (MacOS or iOS), it saves it as `filename.txt` even though I didn't add the .txt. For example `app.ipa` saves as `app.ipa.txt`. Opening https://example.com/path/to/app.ipa on chrome works fine, but when on Safari it adds .txt to the end.

My .htaccess file is like this:

```
# Prevent Rewrites
RewriteEngine off

<Files *.*>
    # Force Download 
    ForceType application/octet-stream # Disable PHP
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    Header set Content-Description: File Transfer
    Header set Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

    # Header set Cache-Control: must-revalidate
    Header set Pragma: public
</Files>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>

# Disable PHP
php_flag engine off
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What would be the point of downloading a .ipa on ios anyway?  That isn't how you can install an app

Comment: @Paulw11 There are other reasons to download IPA files, for example to sideload it manually.

Comment: What Content-Type header (if any) is returned by the server?

Comment: @CBroe its application/octet-stream

Comment: Could it have something to do with what https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239319 mentions? That Safari does some additional checks on the file content, and gets cranky when the supplied Content-Type doesn't actually match that, in the way Safari thinks it should? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13070625/1427878